# Combine Dataframe rows to fill in missing data

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a dataframe with rows containing missing data, but a set of columns acting as a key:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {"id": [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4 ,4], "name": ["John", "John", "Paul", "Paul", "Ringo", "Ringo", "George", "George"], "height": [178, np.nan, 182, np.nan, 175, np.nan, 188, np.nan], "weight": [np.nan, np.NaN, np.nan, 72, np.nan, 68, np.nan, 70]}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
print(df)


id    name  height  weight
0   1    John   178.0     NaN
1   1    John     NaN     NaN
2   2    Paul   182.0     NaN
3   2    Paul     NaN    72.0
4   3   Ringo   175.0     NaN
5   3   Ringo     NaN    68.0
6   4  George   188.0     NaN
7   4  George     NaN    70.0
```

How would I go about "squashing" these rows with duplicate keys down to pick the non-nan value (if it exists)?

```
desired output:
id    name  height  weight
0   1    John   178.0     NaN
2   2    Paul   182.0     72.0
4   3   Ringo   175.0     68.0
6   4  George   188.0     70.0
```

The index doesn't matter, and there is always at most one row with Non-NaN data. I think I need to use `groupby(['id', 'name'])`, but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are always only one non `NaN`s values per groups is possible aggregate many ways:

```
df = df.groupby(['id', 'name'], as_index=False).first()
```

Or:

```
df = df.groupby(['id', 'name'], as_index=False).last()
```

Or:

```
df = df.groupby(['id', 'name'], as_index=False).mean()
```

Or:

```
df = df.groupby(['id', 'name'], as_index=False).sum(min_count=1)
```